# scraping script returning errors like 'subscript out of bounds' and 'object not found' when it works on other pages of the same site

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I have had issues when modifying this working script, which scrapes data from fangraphs, to a different page on the very same site for minor league data. I changed the URL, removed the section about substituting percents because they are no trouble on my specific page and .....

this is the original script

```
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(rvest))

### Load data from webpage

url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=30&type=2&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&page=1_1000"

l1 <- read_html(url)
l1 <- html_nodes(l1, 'table')

### Extract table from html and remove 'bad' rows
fangraphs <- html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)[[12]] 
fangraphs <- fangraphs[-c(1,3),]

# Extract column names
columnNames <- as.list(fangraphs[1,])
# Take care of symbols in column names
columnNames <- gsub("%", ".p", columnNames)
columnNames <- gsub("/", "per", columnNames)

# Rename data frame and remove row with column names
colnames(fangraphs) <- columnNames
fangraphs <- fangraphs[-1,]

fangraphs[] <- sapply(fangraphs, function(x) gsub(" %","",x))
fangraphs[4:19] <- sapply(fangraphs[4:19],as.numeric)
```

this is my edited script to fit this URL (https://www.fangraphs.com/minorleaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,30,46,45,44,32,23&season=2018&team=0&players=&page=1_3000)

```
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(rvest))

### Load data from webpage

url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/minorleaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,30,46,45,44,32,23&season=2018&team=0&players=&page=1_3000"

l1 <- read_html(url)
l1 <- html_nodes(l1, 'table')

### Extract table from html and remove 'bad' rows
fangraphs <- html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)[[12]] 
fangraphs <- fangraphs[-c(1,3),]

# Extract column names
columnNames <- as.list(fangraphs[1,])

# Rename data frame and remove row with column names
colnames(fangraphs) <- columnNames
fangraphs <- fangraphs[-1,]

fangraphs[3:26] <- sapply(fangraphs[3:26],as.numeric)
```

I get this error returned

```
> suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
> suppressMessages(library(rvest))
> 
> ### Load data from webpage
> 
> url <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/minorleaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,30,46,45,44,32,23&season=2018&team=0&players=&page=1_3000"
> 
> l1 <- read_html(url)
> l1 <- html_nodes(l1, 'table')
> 
> ### Extract table from html and remove 'bad' rows
> fangraphs <- html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)[[12]] 
Error in html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)[[12]] : subscript out of bounds
> fangraphs <- fangraphs[-c(1,3),]
Error: object 'fangraphs' not found
> 
> # Extract column names
> columnNames <- as.list(fangraphs[1,])
Error in as.list(fangraphs[1, ]) : object 'fangraphs' not found
> 
> # Rename data frame and remove row with column names
> colnames(fangraphs) <- columnNames
Error in colnames(fangraphs) <- columnNames : 
  object 'fangraphs' not found
> fangraphs <- fangraphs[-1,]
Error: object 'fangraphs' not found
> 
> fangraphs[3:26] <- sapply(fangraphs[3:26],as.numeric)
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'fangraphs' not found
```

and it doesn't get better when i changed the code in html_nodes from 'table' to '#MinorBoard1_dg1_ctl00 .rgHeader , .grid_line_regular' which I picked up using the selector gadget (though this includes the names of each column too.

One final seperate question is whether I need some code to fix the columns that have '.' before they get converted to numeric columns (here I'm talking about the ISO, BABIP, and AVG stats.

Comment: Your code is only returning you a list with `[[5]]` elements in it. So when you call `html_table(l1, fill = TRUE)[[12]] ` you're asking for the `[[12]]` element which doesn't exist.

Comment: @dylanjm but even when i correct that in my code and return head(fangraphs) just after after i extract I get this returned - [1] X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)